# How to get extras without a key?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bundle

As is known to all, we can put the extra info into an Intent by using `putExtra/putExtras`, and pass it to another app. At the destination, we can use `getxxxExtra/getExtras` to get this information. However, all these methods request a key.

I was wondering if there is any way to obtain information without a key.
Or, is there any way to check all the keys that have been set into the bundle?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> if there is any way to obtain information without a key.

No, there is no way to send data without any key, You need to use some sort of key whether it's `Intent.EXTRA` or your defined key

> is there any way to check all the keys that have been set into the
>   bundle?

Yes, you can use `getIntent().getExtras().keySet()` this will give you a `Set` (of String) containing all keys.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Set<String> bundleKeySet = bundle.keySet(); // string key set
for(String key : bundleKeySet){ // traverse and print pairs
    Log.i(key," : " + bundle.get(key));
}
```